# アクセスコントロールで、「オブジェクトの読み込み」権限がないのはなぜ？

Tags: aws

aws の S3 で、アクセスコントロール(ACL) を用いて制御を行おうと考えました。

設定可能な項目として、

- オブジェクトのリスト化
- オブジェクトの書き込み
- バケットの読み取りアクセス権限
- バケットの書き込みアクセス権限

がありますが、

- オブジェクトの読み込み

が設定項目として存在していないのはなぜなのでしょうか。

Answer (score 1):

ACLで バケットにREADを許可した場合は「バケット内のオブジェクトをリストすることを許可」となります。

また、オブジェクトにREADを許可した場合は「オブジェクトデータとそのメタデータを読み込むことを許可」となります。

従って、「オブジェクトの読み込み」を制限したい場合はオブジェクトに対してACLを設定するか、ACLではなくバケットポリシーで `s3:Get*` を禁止するようにしてみてください。

詳しくは開発者ガイドを御覧ください。
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ja_jp/AmazonS3/latest/dev/acl-overview.html#permissions